# Tensor Product of Quaternion Algebras (don't understand two steps in the proof)

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

I am looking at a proof of $$(\frac{a,b}{F})\otimes(\frac{c,d}{F})\cong(\frac{a,bd}{F})\otimes(\frac{ac,d}{F})$$ which goes like this:

Consider $A:=(\frac{a,b}{F})\otimes(\frac{c,d}{F})$. Set $\mathbb{1}=1\otimes 1$, $I=i\otimes 1$, $J=j\otimes j$ and $K=k\otimes j$. Then $\{\mathbb{1},I,J,K\}$ spans a subalgebra $C$ isomorphic to $(\frac{a,bd}{F})$.

Similarly, $I'=i\otimes i$, $J'=1\otimes j$ and $K'=i\otimes k$ and $\{\mathbb{1},I',J',K'\}$ spans a subalgebra $D$ isomorphic to $(\frac{ac,d}{F})$.

So far so good, I can sort of understand.

**The next two steps I don't understand.**

One checks that $xy=yx$ for all $x\in C,y\in D$ (why do we have to check this?) and $C\otimes D\cong CD=A$ (how do we see this?).

Thanks for help!

Notation:
$A$ is a four dimensional $F$-space (where $F$ is a field with characteristic not equal to 2), with basis $\{1,i,j,k\}$, such that $i^2=a$, $j^2=b$, $ij=-ij=k$, where $a,b\in F$.

Then $A$ is an $F$-algebra called the generalized quaternion algebra over $F$, denoted $(\frac{a,b}{F})$.

Comment: We cannot read your mind... What is $F$? What are $a,b,c,d$? And so on.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi I updated some info regarding the notation at the end of the question. $F$ is a field with characteristic not equal to 2. $a,b,c,d$ are elements in the field.

Comment: I don't understand. Presumably $F$ is finite (otherwise I don't understand the finite field tag). But by Wedderburn's theorem there are no finite non-commutative division algebras, so all generalized quaternion algebras over $F$ should split. Consequently the theorem is kinda trivial?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen "finite field" was a wrong tag. I have removed it