# How a multiplication operation is defined in $4$-tuple

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, quaternions

Let $R$ be a commutative ring. Let $S$ be a collection of pairs $(a,b)$ of elements  of $R$. Define addition and multiplication as follows - $$ (a,b)+(a',b') = (a+a',b+b')  $$ and $$(a, b) · (a', b') = (a · a' +b · b' · r, a · b' +a' · b) $$  where $r \in R$

Likewise, now I have to define a multiplication rule for 4-tuple $$(0, 1, 0, 0)^2 = r ; (0, 0, 1, 0)^2 = s ; (0, 1, 0, 0)·(0, 0, 1, 0) = (0, 0, 0, 1) = −(0, 0, 1, 0)·(0, 1, 0, 0)$$ for some $r,s \in R$. (possibly different $r,s$ than for 2-tuple case)

I don't understand how this is defined. How did  we got $(0, 1, 0, 0)·(0, 0, 1, 0) = (0, 0, 0, 1)$?

Comment: What is $(0,1,0,0)^2=r$ supposed to mean?  Especially the $^2$ I can't make sense of.  Is this $r$ the same $r$ in your multiplication rule...?

Comment: Given the quaternions tag, I guess the idea is to describe how to multiply the basis elements of $R^4$ (as an $R$-module) and extend by linearity. As to the question, it's a definition, not derived.

Comment: The 4-tuple rule looks like quaternions?

Comment: @stewbasic but it's defined for a particular case. How do I generalize this rule?

Comment: @mathematician I edited my question

Comment: Is your question, how do you write down a general multiplication rule that satisfies the list of equations you wrote?

Comment: @EricWofsey pretty much

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see, you mean to talk about the generalized quaternions as seen [in this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1671872/29335). You don't deduce any of those relations: you need them all to be *given* so that you can multiply.

To find the general form of the product of two $4$-tuples, you just enforce linearity of multiplication on those generators with those relations.

So, $$(\alpha_1, \alpha_2,\alpha_3,\alpha_4)(\beta_1, \beta_2,\beta_3,\beta_4) \\ 
=(\alpha_1(1,0,0,0)+\alpha_2(0,1,0,0)+\alpha_3(0,0,1,0)+\alpha_4(0,0,0,1))(\beta_1(1,0,0,0)+\beta_2(0,1,0,0)+\beta_3(0,0,1,0)+\beta_4(0,0,0,1)) \\ 
=\alpha_1\beta_1 (1,0,0,0) +\alpha_1\beta_2(0,1,0,0)+\alpha_1\beta_3(0,0,1,0)+\alpha_1\beta_4(0,0,0,1) \\
+ \alpha_2\beta_1(0,1,0,0)+r\alpha_2\beta_2(1,0,0,0)+\alpha_2\beta_3(0,0,0,1)+r\alpha_2\beta_4(0,0,1,0) \\
+\alpha_3\beta_1 (0,0,1,0)-\alpha_3\beta_2(0,0,0,1)+s\alpha_3\beta_3(1,0,0,0)-s\alpha_3\beta_4(0,1,0,0) \\ 
+ \alpha_4\beta_1 (0,0,0,1) -r\alpha_4\beta_2(0,0,1,0)+s\alpha_4\beta_3(0,1,0,0)-rs\alpha_4\beta_4(1,0,0,0) \\ 
=(\alpha_1\beta_1+r\alpha_2\beta_2+s\alpha_3\beta_3-rs\alpha_4\beta_4)(1, 0, 0, 0) \\
+(\alpha_1\beta_2+\alpha_2\beta_1-s\alpha_3\beta_4+s\alpha_4\beta_3)(0, 1, 0, 0) \\
+(\alpha_1\beta_3+r\alpha_2\beta_4+\alpha_3\beta_1-r\alpha_4\beta_2)(0, 0, 1, 0) \\
+(\alpha_1\beta_4+\alpha_2\beta_3-\alpha_3\beta_2+\alpha_4\beta_1)(0, 0, 0, 1)
$$

So there in the last step, you have the generali mutliplication rule. I proofread as best I could a couple times... hopefully if any typos are here someone will help. (At least in the normal case when $r=s=-1$ the equations hold correctly, I think.)

Answer (score 1):

What's missing in the description is that the ring you make the set of $4$-tuple into should be an $R$-algebra and that elements are
$$
(a,b,c,d)=a(1,0,0,0)+b(0,1,0,0)+c(0,0,1,0)+d(0,0,0,1)
$$
or you wouldn't be able to do anything with the given relations.

If you write $u=(1,0,0,0)$, $i=(0,1,0,0)$, $j=(0,0,1,0)$, $k=(0,0,0,1)$, another implicit assumption should be that $u$ is the ring identity and that elements $a\in R$ are identified with $au=(a,0,0,0)$. The given relations now read
$$
i^2=r,\quad j^2=s,\quad ij=k=-ji
$$
The ring properties now help in deducing the other “elementary” products:
$$
ik=i(ij)=i^2j=rj,\quad
ik=i(-ji)=-(ij)i=-ki,\\
jk=j(ij)=(ji)j=-kj,\quad
jk=j(-ji)=-j^2i=-si
$$
Moreover, being the ring an $R$-algebra means elements of $R$ (or $4$-tuples of the form $(a,0,0,0)$) commute with every element.

Now, considering $(a,b,c,d)=a+bi+cj+dk$ and $(a',b',c',d')=a'+b'i+c'j+d'k$ you can write the product
$$
(a,b,c,d)(a',b',c',d')=(a+bi+cj+dk)(a'+b'i+c'j+d'k)
$$
using distributivity, commutativity of “scalars” and the above elementary products. Just tedious work.